# GitHub Merge branch 'master'

Tags: git, github

Been trying out Git and Github after many years of svn use. I seem to have the basics down, but one item is confusing me.

- UserA makes a change to FileA and pushes to the remote server
  (GitHub)
- UserB makes a change to FileB. He first pulls from remote
  server, and then pushes his change to FileB to the remote server
- GitHub commit history shows the push from UserA and the push from UserB
- However, there is an additional entry in the commit history from UserB called 'Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/xxx/yyy'. Viewing the diff in Github shows this to be an exact replica of the Changes that UserA made to FileA

Why is this duplicate shown - both the push from UserA to FileA and the Merge branch master entries are identical...the second seems superfluous to me.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Each version ("commit") stored in git forms part of a graph, and it's frequently helpful to think about what you're doing in git in terms of that graph.

When UserA begins, let's say that there had only been two commits created, which we'll call `P` and `Q`:

```
P--Q (master)
```

He then modifies FileA, stages that change and creates a commit that represents the new state of the source code - let's say that commit is called `R`.  This has a single parent, which is the commit `Q`:

```
P--Q--R (master)
```

After successfully pushing, the commit graph for the GitHub repository looks the same.

UserB started with the same history:

```
P--Q (master)
```

... but created a different commit, say called `S`, which has his modified version of FileB:

```
P--Q--S (master)
```

UserB tries to push that to GitHub, but the push is refused - unless you "force" the push, you're not allowed to update a remote branch unless the version you're pushing includes all of the history in that remote branch.  So, UserB pulls from GitHub.  A pull really consists of two steps, fetching and merging.  The fetch updates `origin/master`, which is like a cache of the state of the remote branch `master` from the remote `origin`.  (This is an example of a "remote-tracking branch".)

```
P--Q--S (master)
    \
      R (origin/master)
```

The history in this graph has diverged, so the merge tries to unify those two histories by creating a merge commit (say `M`) which has both `S` and `R` as parents, and hopefully represents the changes from both branches:

```
P--Q--S--M (master)
    \   /
     \ /
      R (origin/master)
```

When GitHub shows you a diff that represents the changes introduced by the commit, it's simple in the case of a commit with one parent - it can just do a diff from that version.  However, in the case of a commit such as `M`, with more than one parent, it has to choose a parent to show the diff against.  That explains why the diff shown for the merge commit `M` might appear to be the same as that shown for one of `S` or `R`.  Commits in git are defined by the exact state of the source tree, not the changes that got the tree into that state.

Comment: Does this mean that if UserB only modified and pushed FileB after he had pulled the changes on FileA, then the Merge branch 'master' would not be created? If yes, then I think I understand.

Comment: Yes, if UserB pulls before creating the commit that introduces the change to FileB, there'll be no merge commit - it's just like creating any other commit with a single parent.

Comment: It's worth also noting that (a) many people use `git pull --rebase` to keep history linear - after fetching, that will try to reapply any commits that aren't in `origin/master` and (b) if the commit you're trying to merge into your current branch already contains the history of your current branch, by default git won't create a merge commit - it just "fast-forwards" your branch to the state of the one you're merging in.

Comment: We set our remote branches to `git pull --rebase` automatically using `git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always`. Individual branches can be set using `git config branch.<branch>.rebase true`.This prevents these additional merge commits from being introduced. It keeps the history more consistent and regular.