# How to get rid of constant "merge branch" from github by git

Tags: git, github, merge, workflow

I have the following scenario that was explained on the following link:
[GitHub Merge branch 'master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120199/github-merge-branch-master)

I have accepted the fact that with github the action of "merge branch ..." is needed so that we understand that we took a pull request and merged it in.

However 896 commits later with several co-workers I have way too many:
'Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/xxx/yyy'
and
Merge pull request #XXX

is there an effective way to collectively have the proper real commit and not just a bunch of Merge with X and Y, then Merge with Pull, etc etc.
about 50% of the commits on master is full of it.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a habit to do rebase pulls (i.e. merges) using:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

This means that instead of having a merge scenario:

```
A---------M
 \       /
  B-----C
```

You'll have a simple rebase:

```
A--B----C
```

If all team members do this, it will significantly reduce the number of merge commits you see in the history.

Comment: What happens if your the one that is doing it and your doing pull requests via github. When I click MERGE i get those "merge" branch already.

Comment: Ask your collaborators to rebase their feature branches (`git checkout feature && git rebase master`). If the pull request is a fast-forward merge (as is the case after rebasing), no merge commits are created.